# How to store specific values from a data frame to a variable in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 'Age' column and its values are as below:

Age
12
15
16
20
23
24
20
15
16
20
26
20

I want to create a variable and store in it the count of 20 i.e number of people with age as 20.

Can someone please tell me how to do this in R?

Comment: See `table(myDatat$Age)` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a data frame called `data` with a column `age`, you can do this:

```
count <- sum(data$age == 20)
```

Comment: zx8754's answer `table(myDatat$Age)` is probably better as it gives you data about all ages, but this is better if you want to return a number rather than a table.